# V-data-table expand get value on arrow click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js, v-data-table

I'm using a v-data-table with expandable rows. I would like to get the value of a row when the expand arrow is clicked. I know I can use @click:row to get the value when the row is clicked, but specifically clicking on the arrow does not have the same effect. How do I get this value when directly clicking on the expand arrow?

v-data-table below which is fairly basic. I would like to call a method on expansion arrow click that takes the item/object from that row.

```
<v-data-table
    :expanded.sync="expanded"
    :headers="tableHeaders"
    :items="myData"
    :single-expand="true"
    show-expand
 >
```

```
{ text: "", value: "data-table-expand" }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a slot `item:data-table-expand`. You can put your own icon or button in the slot and add a click handler to it.

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/